# How to use environment variables in a Makefile with Zsh?

Tags: makefile, zsh

I have some makefiles that I had written when macOS still used bash.  Now, that macOS has switched to zsh, they no longer work.  I'm wondering how to get the environment variables to work again.  Here's a simple example:

**Makefile:**

```
all:
    echo $(GOPATH)
```

**Bash Output:**

```
$ make
echo /Users/me/go
/Users/me/go
```

**Zsh Output:**

```
% make
echo
```

Comment: Is `GOPATH` defined before you are invoking _make_? The _make_ program itself does not know which shell it was invoked from.

Comment: GOPATH is defined in my environment.  In both shells, echo $GOPATH will return /Users/me/go in both

Comment: Sure it's an *environment* variable? Try `env | grep GOPATH`. Perhaps it's a local variable in zsh.

Comment: `echo` is not sufficient. Do a `printenv GOPATH` just before invoking `make`.

Comment: Just to be very clear: in your bash configuration you've used `export GOPATH` so that the value is both local and exported to subprocesses.  In your zsh configuration you've not exported `GOPATH` so the value is available only in the shell and not exported to subprocesses (like, for example, `make`).